# Geoserver NETCDF file store updates

Tags: geoserver, netcdf, geoserver-rest-api

I am looking for a general approach to "refreshing" a NETCDF store using the REST API.

I have a NETCDF file that is generated every 24 hours.

I need to update the file, but would prefer not having to recreate each layer, as there are many.

I thought perhaps I could rename the coverage store and replace the backing file, then name it back to the original coverage store name, but I am unsure if that will trigger geoserver to reprocess the contained information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I received from the super helpful folks on the geoserver mailing list was to create a mosaic of the various netcdf files, adding and removing individual files to the mosaic as necessary.